# Having trouble removing comma from toLocaleDateString

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have a forum and I'm trying to display the date on topics like this: `9/21 2:09 AM`

I've got it mostly working but there's a comma after the month/day so it ends up looking like this : `9/21, 2:09 AM`.

The unnecessary comma after `9/21` is what's getting to me. I've been trying to find a way to remove it but not having any luck. I've tried separating both the month/date and the time which is what was suggested in another thread but that was giving me ejs errors.

Here is my GET which sets up the options for month/time.

```
router.get("/", async function (req, res, next) {
  const options = {
    month: "numeric",
    day: "numeric",
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "2-digit",
  };

  const [list_topic] = await Promise.all([
    Topic.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 }).exec(),
  ]);
  res.render("index", { list_topic, options });
});
```

And here is what is displayed inside my index page.

```
<% list_topic.forEach(topic => { %>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <span>
         <a href="/topic"> <%=topic.title %> </a>
       </span>
     </td>
     <td><span> <%=topic.author %> </span></td>
     <td>
       <span>
         <%= topic.createdAt.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options) %>
       </span>
     </td>
  </tr>
<% }); %>
```

It works perfectly fine. Just can't get rid of that comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
topic.createdAt.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options).split(",").join("")
```